# Populate View selected record ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I am trying to use a ViewModel as I like the way it validates.

My ViewModel:

```
public class CCvm
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your Name")]
    public string cardHolderName { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your Credit Card Number")]
    public string cardNumber { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your Expiration Date MMYY")]
    [StringLength(4, ErrorMessage = "Expiration Date Format MMYY", MinimumLength = 4)]
    public string cardExpirtyDate { get; set; }

    public Wholesale wholesale { get; set; }
}
```

How can I pass the selected person in wholesaler and the card info to the view?

My Controller:

```
public ActionResult Pay()
{
    if (Session["wID"] == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    ViewBag.Step = 2;
    if (Session["wID"] == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    //Wholesale wholesale = db.Wholesales.Find(Session["wID"]);
    int wID=Convert.ToInt32(Session["wID"]);
    CCvm ccvm = new CCvm();
    var dude = from d in db.Wholesales
               where d.ID==wID
               select d;
    ccvm.wholesale = (dude.ToList());
    if (ccvm == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(ccvm);
}
```

View has fields from the Wholesaler table that i want to use the VM to validate and the controller to update. It also has card info I need the VM to validate and pass to the controller for processing.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { htmlAttributes = new { @placeholder = "First Name Please", @class = "text-danger" } })

<input type="text" name="cardExpirtyDate" style="width:40px" />MMYY
<br />@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.cardExpirtyDate)
```

Comment: I would take the same approach as the credit card fields and add LastName, FirstName, etc. at the same level. Another option would be a Wholesale ViewModel. IAC, you could use automapper to ease the pain. https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/06/30/how-we-do-mvc-view-models/

Comment: Steve, I was going down the automapper route but ran out of time. If you post some code as an answer i would really appreciate it and of course mark as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the project, you can use Model-View-ViewModel Pattern (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Ff798384.aspx). Here is a good article on the topic using automapper: https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/06/30/how-we-do-mvc-view-models

If you want to see arguments for the counter side, here is an article that debates the points: http://www.uglybugger.org/software/post/friends_dont_let_friends_use_automapper

Personally, I've found the ViewModel pattern with automapper to work really well for forms over data type projects.